# Slideshow not working after SSL installation

Tags: javascript, html, ssl

I have recently got a SSL through Lets Encrypt. I had a slideshow script that was workings perfectly, but now I'm having a problem. Instead of loading https://URL/img/slideimg1.png it is loading https://URLimg/slideimg1.png!

```js
document.getElementById("left").style.opacity =1;

var currentSlide = 2;

var refreshSlideInterval = setInterval(changeSlide, 5000);

function changeSlide() {
    if (currentSlide == 1) {
      currentSlide++;
      document.getElementById("slide1IMG").src = 'https://theskindealer.com/img/slideimg1.png';

      document.getElementById("left").style.opacity =1;
      document.getElementById("right").style.opacity =.5;

     } else if (currentSlide == 2) {
      currentSlide++;
      document.getElementById("slide1IMG").src = 'https://theskindealer.com/img/slideimg2.png';

      document.getElementById("middle").style.opacity =1;
      document.getElementById("left").style.opacity =.5;

     } else {
      --currentSlide;
      --currentSlide;
      document.getElementById("slide1IMG").src = 'https://theskindealer.com/img/slideimg3.png';

      document.getElementById("right").style.opacity =1;
      document.getElementById("middle").style.opacity =.5;

    }
}

function firstSlide() {
  currentSlide = 1;
  changeSlide();

  // Reset the interval
  clearInterval(refreshSlideInterval);
  refreshSlideInterval = setInterval(changeSlide, 5000);
}
function secondSlide() {
  currentSlide = 2;
  changeSlide();

  // Reset the interval
  clearInterval(refreshSlideInterval);
  refreshSlideInterval = setInterval(changeSlide, 5000);
}
function thirdSlide() {
  currentSlide = 3;
  changeSlide();

  // Reset the interval
  clearInterval(refreshSlideInterval);
  refreshSlideInterval = setInterval(changeSlide, 5000);
}
```

Not sure if I can give links for help, but the website is theskindealer.com
You will see errors in inspect there!
Thanks in advance for all help and recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of the 404 not found image that created the error --> https://theskindealer.com/img/slide1.png

From browser inspect element I found it should be https://theskindealer.com/img/slideimg1.png instead?

Comment: Sorry, They were originally called slide.png slide2.png.... But I read something online that it was a sort of cache error so I deleted and renamed. I changed the link in the html file, but I am still having troubles once it cycles. Why is it not putting a / after .com? It says in inspect image not resolved at https://theskindealer.comimg/slideimg1.png as it should be https://theskindealer.com/img...

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what did it. But it seems as if it fixed itself? Weird...